# How to show subscribe button next to my name in TechCrunch?

Tags: facebook

I want to show  "Subscribe" button next to my name in TechCrunch when I am logged in as Facebook user.

Presently it is showing my college name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"You" should be able to see it once the "subscribe" button is allowed on your account on Facebook.

Where "You" refers to everyone else watching your Facebook profile.

You (where you refers to... you) cannot subscribe to yourself so it wouldn't make sense showing the subscribe feature for the user currently logged in.

Comment: +1, How can I check what you are saying is in fact the case?

Comment: @codingcrow The only way currently would be to ask a friend to see their view. Test accounts cannot be used to check. To check whether your subscribe button is enabled on your profile, select "View As"